# handle a file upload from a html page to a separate .NET page

Tags: .net, javascript, file, upload

I want to upload a file from a web application.  The web application calls web services to access .NET classes, but it's not a .NET application itself.

What I want to do is this:  upload a file from the web application, and call a separate .NET page to process and handle the uploaded file.

It would be easy to do this if I used a php script to process the uploaded file, but I particularly want to use .NET to process it.

Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy.

```
Request.Files
```

will handle that. To make it work, you should submit it as a valid HTML `multipart/form-data` POST request.

[MSDN Library: HttpRequest.Files property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.files.aspx)

The other option is to post the entire file as the request body (which is probably easier from the sender application's perspective) and then use [`Request.BinaryRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.binaryread.aspx) method or [`Request.InputStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.inputstream.aspx) to process it. I've personally used the latter method in an application that needed to upload images to a Web server:

```
byte[] image = context.Request.BinaryRead(context.Request.ContentLength);
```